# Java 8 using ECIES cipher with a SealedObject fails with 'NullPointerException' - string cannot be null

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, bouncycastle

I am trying to use a ECIES cipher to instantiate a SealedObject, but it fails with a `NullPointerException`. I am using Java JDK1.8.0_72 with Bouncy Castle *bcprov-jdk15on v1.53* running on Windows 10. The code looks like this:

```
KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("ECIES");
kpg.initialize(new ECGenParameterSpec("secp256r1"));
KeyPair keyPair = kpg.generateKeyPair();

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("ECIES");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keyPair.getPublic());

String toEncrypt = "Hello";

// Check that cipher works ok
cipher.doFinal(toEncrypt.getBytes());

// Using a SealedObject to encrypt the same string fails with a NullPointerException
SealedObject sealedObject = new SealedObject(toEncrypt, cipher);
```

The code successfully calls 'cipher.doFinal()' but fails when instantiating the SealedObject.  The stack trace is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: string cannot be null
at org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1OctetString.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.bouncycastle.asn1.DEROctetString.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.ies.AlgorithmParametersSpi.engineGetEncoded(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AlgorithmParameters.getEncoded(AlgorithmParameters.java:362)
at javax.crypto.SealedObject.<init>(SealedObject.java:179)
```

I'm trying to avoid specifying a particular provider (i.e. Bouncy Castle) and avoiding any provider-specific classes such as IESParameterSpec because the component uses external configuration to specify the algorithms to be used.  The component is intended to be used as part of a messaging library in a fluid cluster of nodes where each node may use a different algorithm for encryption, so a SealedObject seems like a reasonable choice because it can be used to pass the algorithm used (any message that uses encryption uses the receiver's public key so the receiver must have the corresponding private key to decrypt the message).

Any thoughts or suggestions would be most welcome.

Comment: Have you tried setting an IV? I'm not 100% on the specifics of this call, but I think it now uses CBC mode encryption... Otherwise it is a question of running the Bouncy code in a debugger.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Thanks for having a look.  I debugged the call and `cipher.spi.engineSpec.derivation` and `.encoding` are both null.  If I initialize the cipher with `new IESParameterSpec("".getBytes(), "".getBytes(), 256)` then the `SealedObject` constructor works.  However, **IESParameterSpec** is specific to Bouncy Castle (package **org.bouncycastle.jce.spec**) and I'm trying to avoid provider-specific code.

Comment: Sounds like a good reason for a feature request at the Bouncy Castle dev mailing list. Should not be too hard to fix - if accepted, but fixing may take some time...

Comment: Thanks Maarten, I've posted this on the Bouncy Castle dev mailing list as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

David Hook at Bouncy Castle had a look and identified an issue in `org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.ies.AlgorithmParametersSpi.engineGetEncoded` and provided a fix in *1.55b04*.  I tested this out and it has resolved this issue.

Thanks again for your help Maarten.